# Android numberpicker locks application

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am trying to use the android.widget.NumberPicker but limiting the range to 0 - 5. However, this seems to cause my application to lock up. Initially the up/down buttons aren't available highlighting the box makes one appear but pressing it several times causes the application to stop responding.

```
    final NumberPicker numerOnePicker  = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numericOnePicker);    
    numerOnePicker.setMinValue(0);
    numerOnePicker.setMaxValue(4);
```

And the XML is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="20dp"> 

<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numericOnePicker"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Voted up, for me this only occurs when I set NumberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel to false. The only indication of a problem I get from LogCat is a persisent stream of 'GC_CONCURRENT freed' messages.